# CDI Injection failed on parent abstract class

Tags: ejb-3.0, java-ee-6, cdi, ejb-3.1

is there a problem injecting a session scope named component in a parent abstract class?

Here's the setup:
I have an interface:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE })
public @interface CurrentTeacher { }
```

Which I use to produce current student (in session scoped):

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class CurrentStudentBean implements Serializable {
    @Produces
    @Named("currentTeacher")
    @currentTeacher
    public Teacher getCurrentTeacher() {
        //...
        return currentTeacher;
    }
}
```

The quite confusing part of how I injected it in order.

page.xhtml->UserBean.java

page.xhtml:

```
<p:commandButton action="userBean.deleteSubject()" value="delete" />
```

Contains an action to delete a subject.

```
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class StudentBean.java extends BaseBean {
  @Inject
  StudentService studentService;
}

public abstract class BaseBean { 
  @Inject
  @CurrentTeacher
  private Teacher currentTeacher; //injection OK    

  public void deleteSubject() { 
    getService().deleteSubject();
    //returns studentService from UserBean and calls BaseService.deleteSubject();
  }
}

@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class StudentService extends BaseService {
}

public abstract class BaseService {
  @Inject
  @CurrentTeacher
  private Teacher currentTeacher; //injection FAILED, currentTeacher always null

  public void deleteSubject() {
    if(currentTeacher != null) { //do something }
  }

  public Student getTeacher() {
    return currentTeacher;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your producer for currentStudent? You only have shown the inject for currentTeacher.  BTW, your currentTeacher injection may work, but isn't portable.  You should always be injecting it as `@Inject @CurrentTeacher private Teacher currentTeacher;`

Comment: Sorry that was also currentTeacher. Kindly look at the updated code above. And yes I always use @CurrentTeacher qualifier.